# Contextual value when the filter is not available and PHP code

Tags: 7, views

I have block view that should be rendered in the node details page. i.e `/node/*`. The block should render latest 6 nodes published under the Category `category_field` that the node has its value.

However, the URL is rewritten and the category id `tid` is not available. The URL is looks like the following:

`http://example.com/Category/world/the-node-title`

So the contextual filter is not available in the URL. So, I created the following PHP code, shown in the screen shot, to get the category tid and return it:

[image]

In the `node.tpl.php` when I try to `var_dump($node->field_category['und'][0]['tid']);` it returns the number of `tid` of the current node. However, the above demonstrated code seems to be not work in the PHP filter code. When I try to return any available value for an category id such as `19` for example, it works.

In other words, how could I return the current node's category field id to the filter?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the problem from [this resource](https://www.drupal.org/node/1871388) and I have to define the `$node` variable by:

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
```

Then I use the `$node` as shown in the question above.